# How can I filter one column by name, then take value from another column?

Tags: excel, powershell

I am writing a script that will take a url and fetch its certificate information. I already have the certificate portion built out and need help with the excel piece. 
I have all the urls stored in a big excel file.

I can import with

```
$xcel = Import-CSV C:\path\test.csv
```

then I can look at the differnt values in that sheet

```
$xcel | get-member
```

Now here I can see all of the different column names

What I want to do is filter by a column, then take another columns value.

For instance one column has a string of TYPE and the next has a string of URL

I want to sort by specific TYPEs and then take each of those types URL

How can I do this?

I am super new to Powershell (today) and I was trying something like

```
$xcel | foreach{if($_.TYPE -like "example"){$url = $_.URL}}
```

ideally I want to store each of the matching columns URL in a variable to then use in my Certificate function I built to retrieve the certificates.

How can I add additional filters for if and then take each returned URL and pass each one to the Certificate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following if you only care about the URL header:

```
$xcel.where({$_.TYPE -eq "example"}) | Foreach-Object {
    $url = $_.URL
}
```

If you only want to create a collection of URLs, then you can simply do the following. Then `$urls` will be an array of URLs or you can access them individually through a `Foreach-Object` or by index (`$url[0]`, `$url[1]`, etc.).

```
$urls = $xcel.where({$_.TYPE -eq "example"}).URL
```

**Explanation:**

The `.where()` method filters your `$xcel` array only displaying rows where the `TYPE` value is `example`. Those resulting rows are then piped into `Foreach-Object`. `$URL` will hold the value for the URL property for the current pipeline object (`$_`), which is the current row. Within that `Foreach-Object` script block, you can do your remaining actions with `$URL`.

---

An alternative solution would be a slight variation to the first. You can use the `if` statement approach, which may give you more flexibility with each row.

```
$xcel | Foreach-Object {
   if ($_.TYPE -eq "example") {
      $URL = $_.URL
   }
   else {
      $URL = $null
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I did not know about the .where. So both of these lines work as intended. They go through all columns in TYPE and then grab the corresponding URL. But how can I make it so it doesnt just loop through the whole file and end up with one value at the end? How can I instead pass each of those values to my other function to run?

Comment: You have a couple of options in that case. 1) You can call your function during each loop iteration (when $URL changes). 2) You can store all of the URL values into an array and then pass that into function. Depending on how your function is set up, you could pipe directly from this Foreach-Object into your function. How does your function expect to receive input?

Comment: Good question. Right now it is just statically set as a url of "https://github.com" 

I did have a param commented out like 
```
param($url)
```
again, I just started today. Should I post code somewhere to see? 
Also thank you very much for the help

Comment: Well. I did provide an update that stores all of the URLs into one variable `$urls`. If your function only has one parameter, then you could so something like `$urls | Foreach-Object { yourfunction $_ }`. You don't technically even need a variable for URL if you are just passing into another function. You can just call `yourfunction $_.URL` within your original `foreach-object`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!